# Globbing syntax (actually `brace expansion`) with grep: Why doesn't this work?

Tags: bash, grep, glob

I'm trying to find all of the instances of a function while also improving my understanding of grep and globbing.  However, I can't figure out what I'm misunderstanding.

For example, if I don't `glob`, and I want to search for a string in files ending in `Rmd`, I can get the following results

```
$ grep -rl --include="*Rmd" "plotRFPByPosition" .
./R_notebooks/detecting_stall_sites.Rmd
./R_notebooks/effects_of_data_filtering.Rmd
./R_notebooks/impact_of_ramp.Rmd
./Paper/final_analyses_and_plots.Rmd
$
```

Similarly for files ending in `R`, I can get

```
$ grep -rl --include="*R" "plotRFPByPosition" .
./R_notebooks/helperFunctions.R
./Paper/R_notebooks/helperFunctions.R
$
```

But if I want to look for files ending in *either* Rmd or R, this doesn't return anything (not even the previous results.

```
$ grep -rl --include="*{Rmd,R}" "plotRFPByPosition" .
$
```

I've also tried `--include="{*Rmd,*R}"` and `--include="{Rmd,R}"` but none of these work.

What simple aspect about globbing do I misunderstand?

Comment: Brace expansion is not globbing. They're two separate operations. When grep documents that it implements its own version of shell globs, that does not mean it supports brace expansion.

Comment: You might look into whether the version of grep you're using lets you pass `--include` twice (and honors both patterns when that's done). If so you can use `--include="*"{Rmd,R}`, which the shell will rewrite to something equivalent to `--include="*"Rmd --include="*"R`

Comment: `*{Rmd,R}` is not a valid glob pattern. The `grep` man page does not specify, which globbing is supported, but I guess it's more or less [this](https://linux.die.net/man/7/glob).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the clarification on globbing vs. brace expansion.

Comment: Glad to help. Added as a comment earlier because I was on my phone at the time, which wasn't suited to longer-form editing; but since you've indicated that you prefer that that be covered in an answer I've added my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brace expansion is a separate step from globbing, rather than part of the glob operation; it isn't performed by [`fnmatch()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fnmatch.3.html) or [`glob()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html), the two C functions most commonly used for glob-type operations (by programs other than shells, which typically include their own extended globbing engines).

You can use it here, by taking the braces out of quotes:

```
grep -rl --include="*"{Rmd,R} plotRFPByPosition
```

will be rewritten by the shell (performing brace expansion) into:

```
grep -rl --include="*"Rmd --include="*"R plotRFPByPosition
```

...after which point `grep` itself will presumably use `glob()`, `fnmatch()` or similar to filter for files matching either of those patterns.

Answer (score 2):

To use multiple patterns you can use multiple `--include` options.

```bash
grep -rl --include="*Rmd" --include="*R" "plotRFPByPosition"
```

Comment: I just tried @CharlesDuffy's suggestion to use `--include="*"{R,Rmd}` and that works and is closer to my original attempt.  I tried editing @mugiseyebrows answer but the editing queue is full, so I can't *add* as an alternative to the accepted answer (but I'd like to).